# Is there a way to redirect STDERR in Crystal?

Tags: crystal-lang

It would be convenient to redirect `STDERR` during tests. Is this possible in Crystal?

Comment: @OlehPrypin Thanks for a fast answer. Would you like to write it as a separate answer so I can mark it as "accepted"? Unless someone else does it and takes your credit :)

Comment: What is you actual use case for this? It feels to me like you wouldn't need this unless youre maybe testing a test library itself.

Comment: @JohannesMüller  I was testing a shard that occasionally outputs to `STDERR`. I wanted to capture the STDERR output to ignore it. But, I wouldn't use this outside of testing purposes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way of doing it with just the standard library, but there is an external library that does the low-level operation.

https://github.com/mosop/stdio
A small Crystal library for capturing standard I/O streams

Answer (score 2):

Here is one possible way (inspired from https://github.com/mosop/stdio)

`dup2` is included in `Libc`. `dup` has to be defined. You can then capture either STDOUT or STDERR:

```
lib LibC
  fun dup(oldfd : LibC::Int) : LibC::Int
end

def capture(origin)
  close_on_exec = origin.close_on_exec?
  begin
    o, i = IO.pipe
    dup = LibC.dup(origin.fd)
    origin.reopen(i)
    yield o
    LibC.dup2(dup, origin.fd)
    origin.close_on_exec = close_on_exec

  ensure
    o.close if o
    i.flush if i
    i.close if i
  end
end

STDERR.puts "a"
capture(STDERR) { |output|
  STDERR.puts "b\nc"
  puts output.gets.inspect
  puts output.gets.inspect
}
STDERR.puts "d"
capture(STDOUT) { |output| STDOUT.puts "this is ignored" }
puts "done"
```